# Detection of defacts during video rendering ( which algorithm to use)

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, emgucv

I would like the system to pin point/highlight the deformed area to the user during video rendering. Lets say currently I have an image with a list of squares as shown in the image below, this is the original image without defects.

[image]

In the following image, is the sample image that consist of a defect, whereby there is an extra line in between the squares.

[image]

I would like to have something as shown in the sample image below where by it will have a red square to highlight the "extra line" to inform the user that there is a defect and will pin point the defect to the user.

[image]

The defects may appear in any kinds of shapes or forms, and I would like to pin point the defects to the user. So what kind of algorithm I should use in order to achieve this?

Also, is machine learning required in order to achieve this?

Currently I am using Emgucv in C#, but I am not sure what algorithm I should use that can achieve this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just to an cv::absdiff to find the changed areas. After that, use findcontours to group the defects and draw an outline around them.

Comment: Yes, in more general terms.  Subtract the current frame from your expected image.  Areas that are not zero will be the sections of the image that are different.  Find the bounding box around the non-zero area and draw it on the image.  With video the noise will likely cause some difference that you will want to ignore.  Ignore differences smaller than a certain threshold in magnitude and smaller than a certain size.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I had tried this method before but it doesn't seem to work well for me in the real images because it will also look different when viewed from different angles and the real image is metallic. So the image substraction doesn't work well for me

Comment: And why didn't you provide sample images? How do you expect to get a solution for Problem B if you ask for a solution for Problem A?